# Get Ad Set schedule details

Tags: facebook-ads-api

I am currently using:

```
$output = $adset->read(array("campaign_schedule"));
```

Which is similar to:

```
curl -G \
-d "fields=campaign_schedule" \
-d "access_token=___" \
-d "method=get" \
'https://graph.facebook.com/{adset_id}'
```

This returns the campaign_schedule array deep within the response object.

How can I get just the campaign schedule as an array/object?

Documentation here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/adset/pacing/v2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The campaign schedule will be a member variable of the object returned.

```
print_r($adset->campaign_schedule);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand what you're saying in theory, but I don't understand how to do this in practice. The variable I want seems to be inside a protected variable.

Comment: no it's handled by a magic method of the class, so if you just read it, it should work. `$schedule = $adset->campaign_schedule; print_r($schedule);`

Comment: Thanks so much. It seems obvious now, but I didn't understand that the setter was also the getter.